# How to use Code Data in a Cocoa Touch framework in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, cocoa-touch

To use CoreData in swift I used to check the column "use CoreData" when I create a new swift project
I want to the the same creating a cocoa touch framework in swift but there is no column "use CoreData" to check
So how can I do to use CoreData in a cocoa touch framework ??

Answer (score 0):

`use CoreData` only provides you the basic implementation of Core Data for you in code. It doesn't flip any internal switches that "allow" you to use Core Data.

You can use Core Data in any project, if you didn't check the `use CoreData` box, just write out the code required it yourself. It's a good learning experience!

Comment: yes but is there a way to use  CoreData without reffering to Appdelegate ( juste from the framework)

Comment: yes. you can use core data without referring to app delegate